# PHP SOAP Fatal Error

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to integrate cargo system to my website. Then I'm using their webservice.

But I've an error like that:
"Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't find  in "

And error show me that line: 2 second. And that line has that code:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://customerservices.araskargo.com.tr/ArasCargoCustomerIntegrationService/ArasCargoIntegrationService.svc");
```

And here's my full code:

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient("http://customerservices.araskargo.com.tr/ArasCargoCustomerIntegrationService/ArasCargoIntegrationService.svc");
$queryInfo = "<QueryInfo>".
"<QueryType>2</QueryType>".
"<Date>07.10.2015</Date>".
"</QueryInfo>";
$loginInfo = "<LoginInfo>".
"<UserName>xxx</UserName>".
"<Password>xxx</Password>".
"<CustomerCode>xxx</CustomerCode>".
"</LoginInfo>";
$result = $client->GetQueryXML(array('loginInfo'=>$loginInfo,'queryInfo'=>$queryInfo));
echo $result;
```

How can I solve my problem?